# ssh to a machine via a cluster of Jumphost - host key verification fails

Tags: ssh

I have FQDN  : jumphost.mycompany.com
which is a load balancer that distributes the load between 3 different servers

- jumphost1.mycompany.com
- jumphost2.mycompany.com
- jumphost3.mycompany.com

I want to use jumphost.mycompany.com as a Jumphost to execute some SSH commands on a target host

Depending on the underlying hosts we use, we will get a "host key verification failed"

The following command would work :

```
 ssh  -i  ~/.ssh/mykey -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey -o  StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -W %h:%p jumpuser@jumphost.mycompany.com" target-user@target-server.mycompany.com  "myshellcommand"
```

However this defeats the purpose of checking the host key and I am therefore vulnerable to a man in the middle attack.

What would be the best way to overcome this problem ?
Also, how could I translate the previous command with the usage of the J option

Thanks

Comment: If jumphost[123] are supposed to be identical and for load balancing, they should have the same hostkey